# Jmeter View Results tree displaying Multiple urls in single Http Request

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm working on web application performance testing to Create the Customers,i've recorded the script using Recording Controller.Once i execute the same i'm getting failure in View Results Tree because one HTTP Sample loading Multiple URL's under one HTTP Samples as below.

View Results Tree

```
Login
  -http://ipaddress:port/login
  -http://ipaddress:port/registration
Home
  -http://ipaddress:port/login
  -http://ipaddress:port/registration-home
```

In Login sample it got fail because giving error in `registration` page,Please help how to resolve this type issues.

Comment: did you try add cookie manager to test plan?

Comment: No ,not added and i'll try and check

Comment: Can you share a snapshot, that could be a redirection or embedded resources

Comment: did it worked after adding cookie manager to test plan?

Comment: HTTP sample is NOT loading multiple urls. It follows the redirects. As user7294900 pointed out, you need to use cookie manager at the minimum. But since your question has no further details, it's hard to know if cookie manager alone is sufficient or not